# implementing my own malloc

Tags: c++, c, malloc, shared-libraries

I want to create a transparent user level library that changes what `malloc()` does. I want to have my own implementation of `malloc` but I don't want any change in the source code. The code has to be linked with my user library though. Is just defining a `malloc` function in my library enough? or will I run into problems trying to define a function that is already in the c standard library?

Comment: Hmm, be more specific. If the user allocates memory, per say with `new` (C++) tag, would you want your `malloc` to be called? What if a STL library function calls `new`?

Comment: yes. new or malloc in his source code should be implemented by my implementation of malloc.

Comment: @Keeto, the solution to your predicament will most likely differ depending on the language.  I suggest that you first remove either the [c++] or the [c] tag.

Comment: @Keeto, if you elect the [c] route, it would be helpful to know more about the execution environment (ie: Windows, Linux, OS X, etc.).

Comment: @Keeto, are you just implementing 'malloc()'?  What about 'free()', 'realloc()', 'strdup()', etc. ?